# How to run for loop in visual studio with python codes

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am new on Visual Studio and I run python codes but at the end of every row I press shift+enter it works for that line but when there is for loop and at the of the line I press shift+enter it gives me an error mesaage so how can I run for loop in visual studio.
Below is the example how can I run this code?

```
cols = data.columns
for j in cols:
   for i in range(0,len(data)):
       if data[j][i] == -200:
           data[j][i] = data[j][i-1]
```

Thank you

Comment: Show us an example.  Your description doesn't make sense.  And I haven't heard the words "do loop" since Fortran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> runs a single line of code.

To run the whole script at ones you would like to press  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>  or just use the [***Play*** button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK469.png)  on the top right corner